# I have an ajax request and a test calling a Catalyst controller. How do I get the params to show up in the same place in the Catalyst object?

Tags: perl, catalyst

Snippet from the test:

```
my $request = HTTP::Request->new( POST => 'http://192.168.5.130:3000/user' );
$request->content_type('application/json');
$request->content( $query_string );
my $result = $ua->request( $request );
```

Snippet from the ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://192.168.5.130:3000/user',
    type: 'POST',
    cache: false,
    async: true,
    dataType: 'json',
    timeout: 5000,
    data: $("#create-user-form").serializeObject(),
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
    console.log("jQuery ajax error....");
},
);
```

In the controller is the route handler (using `Catalyst::Controller::Rest`)

```
sub user_POST {
        my ($self, $c, $args) = @_;
    warn Dumper( $c );

...
 }
```

The problem I'm having is, when I make the call from the test the content is
set in the Catalyst object in a hash with a key called 'data' which can be 
accessed be calling `$c->req->data`.

However, when the ajax call is made from a webpage, the data is 
held in the Catalyst object in a hash with a key called '*parameters*' which is
accessed by calling `$c->req->parameters`.

Anyone know why this is happening and or what to do to work around it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure, but I would suspect that jQuery is appending the data you are sending in the Ajax request to the GET query string. Part of my doubt is that I do not know what `.serializeObject()` does in your Ajax snippet.

You might check the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) regarding the `data` and `processData` options and see if that helps.

Here are the relevant sections:

> **data**
>   Data to be sent to the server. It is converted to a query string, if not already a string. It's appended to the url for GET-requests. See processData option to prevent this automatic processing. Object must be Key/Value pairs. If value is an Array, jQuery serializes multiple values with same key based on the value of the traditional setting (described below).
>
> ...
>
> **processData**
>   By default, data passed in to the data option as an object (technically, anything other than a string) will be processed and transformed into a query string, fitting to the default content-type "application/x-www-form-urlencoded". If you want to send a DOMDocument, or other non-processed data, set this option to false.

Answer (score 0):

Catalyst stores input in two different places. Query string parameters are made available in

```
$c->request->query_params
```

and body parameters are made available in

```
$c->request->body_params
```

To get all input, use

```
$c->request->params
```

From the documentation of the Catalyst::Controller::REST module:

```
The HTTP POST, PUT, and OPTIONS methods will all automatically deserialize the
contents of $c->request->body into the $c->request->data hashref
```